# Trigger callback after_commit but NOT as a result of touch

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to trigger my callback whenever an object is committed. But I don't want the callback to trigger if the `after_commit` is a result of the object simply being touched. I've looked into `after_update` , `after_update_commit` , and `after_save`, but none of these seem to match the behavior i'm describing. Is there a way to do this other than to have my callback reload the object from the database and verify that a column other than `updated_at` has been modified before proceeding? I'm on Rails 5.2.

Comment: `after_save` seems like the way to go. It's not executed on `touch` ([after_commit](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch) is).

Comment: but I need this callback to occur only after the transaction is complete, whereas `after_save` will get called even if the sql query fails

Comment: When a call to `save` fails, it returns false...which will stop the callback chain (`after_save` will not be executed)

Comment: the other issue is I don't want the transaction to be rolled back if the callback fails. the callback concerns itself with creating sidekiq jobs which will be requeued at a later time if there is a problem with sidekiq or redis or whatever, but shouldn't rollback the transaction. See https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3906 for someone else explaining that particular concern probably more eloquently than i can

Comment: here is a decent article highlighting another reason why `after_save` could lead to problems if used for background jobs: https://rubyinrails.com/2018/12/03/rails-usage-of-after-commit-vs-after-save/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in the end the easiest way I found was to bundle the [ar_transaction_changes](https://github.com/dylanahsmith/ar_transaction_changes/blob/master/lib/ar_transaction_changes.rb) gem. That gem preserves the changes to the record across the transaction and allows me to filter my callbacks like so:

```
# only kick off job if the update is not due to a touch
after_commit :kickoff_job, on: :update, unless: -> { transaction_changed_attributes.keys == ['updated_at'] }
```

this way the callback isnt executed if the `after_commit` is the result of just a touch.